# Problem with dequeue method in array implementation of queue (Python)

Tags: python, data-structures, queue

This is my attempt to code an array implementation of a queue in python. All methods are working fine, but I don't understand why my Dequeue method isn't working. There is no error given by the program but the first item is not being dequeued.

```
class Queue:

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.rear = -1
        self.front = -1  
        self.size = 0  
        self.current_list = []  # This going to be our queue.

    def IsEmpty(self):
        return self.size == 0   

    def IsFull(self):
        return self.size == self.capacity 

    def Enqueue(self, x):

        if self.IsFull():
            return 'This queue is full. Cannot enqueue items.'  
        elif self.IsEmpty():
            self.rear += 1
            self.current_list.append(x)
        else:
            self.rear += 1
            self.current_list[self.rear] = x

    def Dequeue(self):

        if self.IsEmpty():
            return 'Cannot dequeue items as queue is empty.'

        elif self.size == 1:
            self.front +=1
            del self.current_list[self.front]
            self.front, self.rear = -1, -1
        else:
            self.front += 1
            self.current_list.pop(self.front)

    def GetFront(self):
        return self.current_list[self.front]

    def GetRear(self):
        return self.current_list[self.rear]

my_queue = Queue(5)

my_queue.Enqueue(10)
print(my_queue.current_list)
my_queue.Enqueue(5)
print(my_queue.current_list)
my_queue.Dequeue()
print(my_queue.current_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't keeping track of the `size` variable when adding or removing elements. Here's a version I fixed and tested further:

```
class Queue:

def __init__(self, capacity):
    self.capacity = capacity
    self.rear = -1
    self.front = -1  
    self.size = 0  
    self.current_list = []  # This going to be our queue.

def IsEmpty(self):
    return self.size == 0   

def IsFull(self):
    return self.size == self.capacity 

def Enqueue(self, x):
    if self.IsFull():
        return 'This queue is full. Cannot enqueue items.'
    self.rear += 1
    self.current_list.append(x)
    self.size += 1

def Dequeue(self):
    if self.IsEmpty():
        return 'Cannot dequeue items as queue is empty.'
    elif self.size == 1:
        self.current_list.pop()
        self.front, self.rear = -1, -1
    else:
        self.front += 1
        self.current_list.pop(self.front)
    self.size -= 1

def GetFront(self):
    return self.current_list[self.front]

def GetRear(self):
    return self.current_list[self.rear]
```

Comment: Ultimately you can implement the size check by using `len(self.current_list)` but I kept it close to the original.